# z-index doesn't work with ::after/::before element?

Tags: css

z-index doesn't work with its `::before`/`::after` element. Here I'm sharing code below.

```css
.or {
  border: 2px solid #8fc300;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11;
}
.or::after {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 116px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -68px;
  width: 4px;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="or"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove `z-index` from parent element and use negative `z-index: -1` on pseudo element. If you want only green line on red line you need to remove white background from parent also [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1234/)

```css
.or {
  border: 2px solid #8fc300;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
}
.or::after {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 116px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -68px;
  width: 4px;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="or"></div>
```

Comment: Here In my scenario, `.or` lives inside a `modal`, so it must should have a `z-index` value, otherwise if i set `z-index: -1` for `or::after`, it goes under the modal. Is there any solution keeping `z-index` with parent `.or` ?

Comment: Can you create demo for you problem its hard to tell solution without it.

Comment: Please see here. http://jimfahad.com/onewave/3/game-play.html (click on `create account` button - http://prntscr.com/chyqap )

Answer (score 4):

Pseudo-elements are treated as descendants of their associated element. Hence `.or::after` will inherit `z-index: 11` from `.or`.

Just remove `z-index` from `.or` and update `z-index: -1` on `.or::after`

```css
.or {
  border: 2px solid #8fc300;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
}
.or::after {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 116px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -68px;
  width: 4px;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="or"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution.

On the `.or` element, do not set the z-index value and remove the white background (this may not be what you need however).

On the `:after` pseudo-element, set `z-index: -1` and this will cause it to be rendered (painted) under the parent element.

```css
.or {
  border: 6px solid #8fc300;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /*background: #fff;*/
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 11;*/
}
.or::after {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 116px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -68px;
  width: 4px;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="or"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want something like that. I did changed the styling for `.or` class like `background-color: transparent` removed position, z-index and for `.or::after` `z-index: -11`

```css
.or {
  border: 2px solid #8fc300;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 34px;
  margin-top: 64px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  /*position: relative;*/
  /*z-index: 11;*/
}
.or::after {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 116px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-top: -68px;
  width: 4px;
  /*For z-index - keep the green area on top*/
  position: relative;
  z-index: -11;
}
```

```html
<div class="or"></div>
```

Comment: An explanation can make this a better solution.