# element::after z-index not working for it

Tags: html, css, styles, elementor

hey i have a problem with this code:

```css
#selector{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#333;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(50%);
  right: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  width: 95%;
  z-index: 20;
}

#selector::after{
    content: '';
    width: 95%;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: -4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(50%);
    background: #3D74FE;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="selector"></div>
```

u can see that i have a z-index for **#selector::after**, but it doesn't work and it doesn't go behind my **#selector**!!!

Answer (score 0):

Child z-index does not work for its parent

Solution:

```
#selector{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  transform: translate(50%);
  right: 50%;
  top: 10px;
  width: 95%;
  position: relative;
}

#selector::before{
  content: '';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#333;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#selector::after{
    content: '';
    width: 95%;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: -4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(50%);
    background: #3D74FE;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` will not work if you have `transform` property*.

`position` property is anything other than `static`, `relative`, `absolute`*.

*See [reference](https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/).

You can remove `z-index` from parent element (where it should be above blue line). ([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489738/z-index-doesnt-work-with-after-before-element)).

So, new CSS is:

```css
#selector{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#333;
  position: relative;
  /*transform: translate(50%);*/
  /*right: 50%;
  top: 10px;*//* use margin */
  width: 95%;
  /*z-index: 20;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#selector::after{
    content: '';
    width: 95%;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: -4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(50%);
    background: #3D74FE;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="selector"></div>
```

See it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6ua9cdt/).